# Why does the scientist inject himself with the virus?

Tags: plot-explanation, mission-impossible, mission-impossible-2

Why does Nekhorvich inject himself with the virus in *Mission Impossible 2*? He could've just smuggled it in his suitcase like he did with the antidote or simply destroyed it in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

[Straight from IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120755/faq):

> Nekhorvich felt that **this was the most viable way** of getting the virus
>   to the Center for Disease Control (CDC) in Atlanta, i.e., providing it
>   with its optimum environment (in the human body), lessening the
>   chances of losing or breaking a vial, contaminating others, and
>   perhaps the virus being discovered in his baggage by customs agents.
>   He also brought Bellerophon, the antidote, with him so that he could
>   demonstrate to the CDC the effectiveness of the cure.